# Python - String Formatting or String Interpolation for text string from a file

Tags: python, string

I would love to create a python script that loops through a bunch of files in a folder and replaces a bit of formatted text with a variable from the script.

for a (very simplified) example, a folder contains two files:

`greeting.sql` with the text

```
select greeting
from greeting_list
where name = {name}
```

and

`credentials.sql` with the text

```
select credentials
from credentials_list
where name = {name}
```

The python script could then pull in these text files, and interpolate the script, replacing the `{name}` variable in the text with a pre-defined variable, as `name = 'Bob'`.

Something like

```
fd = open('greeting.sql', 'r')
greeting = fd.read()
fd.close()

names = ['Jeff','Melanie','Nitin','Satya','Serena']

[run_sql(greeting.format(n)) for n in names]
```

I usually use interpolated strings, as `f'Greeting for {name} is {greeting}'` so I'm highly confident my usage of `.format()` here doesn't make sense.

The point of this operation would be to allow analysts to update and maintain SQL code, while having a python script pull in the correct version of the script and run it with a variety of variables.

Comment: Seems to me like you want to use a template engine such as [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) or [Mako](https://www.makotemplates.org/)

Comment: these are made for html, not sql; that wouldn't work

Comment: @JulesG.M. No, they are not. They just happen to be bundled in web frameworks as such

Comment: Note: Overall, this seems like a bad idea (SQL Injection) and you should be using prepared statements, not un-escaped template strings

Comment: If you just want to replace the names and run that query, you can loop through the names( for person in names) available and run a greeting.replace(“{name}”, person)

Comment: @OneCricketeer, that's another good option that we use in other contexts. The goal was to be able to manage something pretty quick-and-dirty

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem was very definitely that I was lazy with my `.format()` knowledge because f-strings seemed so much easier. The solution is quite simple:

With the same `greeting.sql` file above,

```
py_name = 'Bob'
print(greeting.format(name = py_name))
```

Works beautifully